# Need help with closing gap on web page

Tags: css, html, charts

I've been trying to figure out how to close this space and I am getting nowhere.

[image]

What could be causing that significant amount of space between the text and the chart? I hope this is the right place to ask this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:  This is the code for it.

[image]

Comment: Most likely to be a code issue that would belong to StackOverflow for now. You will need to provide code if you want someone to be able to help you. Do you have access to it?

Comment: The `<ol>` looks like it might be in a `<div>` with a set height. Posting code would help.

Comment: Learn how to use inspector, like the one [Chrome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mhb4n0yGYT4) has built in. That video is old, but the basic idea is still the same. --- With that, I'm pretty sure you'll be figure out the cause on your own.

Comment: **Squish it up**. That's the best I can do without seeing *any* code.

Comment: Sorry.. new to this forum. I edited the original post and added the code. Thanks for your responses so far. I guess it would help if I posted the code. Doh.

Comment: You need to a) post this on stackoverflow and b) actually link to a live page (JSFiddle will work) so we can debug your markup in the browser.

Comment: Please, paste the code, not an screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cant see the problem anywhere with what you have provided, I recreated that document and tested in multiple browser and i have no gab other than the `</br>` you have after span,
is there a CSS associated with that page somewhere you didnt post ?

Comment: My lead designer informed me today it may be the way our website template is set up. Especially since it seems to be ok in your browser. He's going to try to tweak it today and see if that works. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each physical line with nothing but white space may be getting converted to a `<br>` tag and/or additional padding, an expanded margin, or an increased line-height via css like @DuckStalker suggested.

I've seen similar line-break-to-`<br>`-tag template processing before.